# mod_proxy_wstunnel with cometd running on jetty

Tags: websocket, jetty, mod-proxy, cometd

I am trying to use Apache as a reverse proxy to my Jetty server running cometd.

My setup is working like this:

```
Apache(HTTPS) --> Jetty(HTTP)
```

Here is the Apache conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin xxx@domain.com
        ServerName y.domain.com

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8888/

        ProxyPass /ws/  ws://localhost:8888/
        ProxyPass /wss/ wss://localhost:8888/

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyVia On
        Timeout 1500
        KeepAlive On
        MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
        KeepAliveTimeout 15

        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/localhost.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/localhost.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.crt

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

On the client I'm using cometd.js.

However I'm getting this error on the client during handshake

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

The address is `wss://y.domain.com`

After that the client is trying again and site is up - but I'm afraid the handshake is with long polling...

What am I missing?

Comment: Apache in front of Jetty is a known performance and capability bottleneck, can you explain why you feel the need to use setup?

Comment: well, my application is using 4 different virtual hosting which running on the same server. Some of them use the local apache, and some are using the apache as a reverse proxy. Since I want all of them to run with SSL with port 443, Apache/NGINX seems like the best option. If I run Jetty in native mode (with port 443) then I have to move to 2 different machine which is something I which to avoud.

Answer (score 2):

Ordering of ProxyPass directive matters

> The configured ProxyPass and ProxyPassMatch rules are checked in the order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass